# Parameter is not valid. Bitmap() and NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter()

Tags: c#, bitmap, stream

I wrote this code but got this msg "Parameter is not valid"

```
Stream outputS = Stream.Null;
(new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter()).GetVideoThumbnail(arrayF[indexF].FullName, outputS);
outputS.Position = 0;
System.Drawing.Image thumb = new Bitmap(outputS);
res[0, 1] = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ImageToByte2(thumb));
```

can anyone help me?!!

Comment: Just check any data present in stream outputS

Comment: thanks for quick reply , its length is 0 !!!!!!!!!! it means NReco couldnt fill it???

Comment: yes..that means there is no imagedata present in stream

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you pass Stream.Null as output stream for GetVideoThumbnail method (it always will be empty). Try to use MemoryStream:

```
Stream outputS = new MemoryStream();
```